Is it possible to make a Android Studio Plugin which can interact with its emulator?
I am thinking of building an Android Studio plugin that can monitor and replay user's actions in its emulator. For example, a tester has done a certain series of actions in the emulator. The plugin should be able to record the actions and allow the user to replay the whole flow when they enter this device next time.
Is this possible? I think the closest one is ADB Idea but it seems more likely to use the command in Android Studio rather than doing things directly in the emulator.
UPDATE: I have asked both ChatGPT and Gemini, but they don't seem to provide much insight, just saying that plugins cannot directly interact with the processes in the emulator because of security reasons. Unsure if it is true.
